# Ionic Mobile App - Manage data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I started with Ionic a few weeks ago and now I'm building a mobile app and I have some questions related with the storage/database.

The App is for an event, so it will have an agenda with every session and speakers, etc.. This agenda will have the feature to favourite a session and add it to "My Agenda" so the user can have a personalized one.

Where should I storage all this agenda information? Cloud solution (firebase) or internally in the device? What would be the normal practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should analyze your requirements then decide what storage do you want to use to store data.

I can list out some points which could help you. 
If you want your data to be persistent no matter what device or where the user wants to access his data use firebase because the user can retrieve data regardless of which device he uses and yes user can retrieve their data even after the uninstalling the app and then re installing.(important thing this requires connection to the internet to retrieve user data)

If you store data in phone storage fetching data from phone storage is very easy and will be faster than firebase and will work offline also but the data will be lost if the user uninstalls the app

Comment: I was thinking more about an hybrid option (firebase+phone storage).

I want the best performance for my app, so I was thinking that maybe the first time that the user opens the agenda page I can retrieve the data from firebase and storage in the device, so the next time that the user check the page it will load faster since doesnt have to get the data from the serve.

Same for "My agenda" feature, I can mark a session as fav for a user and keep it in firebase and in the phone storage aswell.

So, If the user uninstall the app I'll always have the data in firebase and can retrieve it.

Comment: Yes exactly if that is the case then as soon as the user logs in check from firebase for any of his data if it is save it to storage and then retrieve that data from any page by just fetching if from your storage that way your app performance will be good, fast and whenever you delete/add manipulate data store it to firebase and update the same in your storage

Comment: Great! Thanks!

One last thing, in developing mode, so the app is not running in the device yet, just in a browser, how can I recreate the phone storage device? Id like to code everything and test it like if it was in the phone already. Thanks!

Comment: For trying on browser you can use localstorge in this case the data will be stored in browser and while on device it will store in device storage no need to worry and change code. But ionic comes with native storage plugin which you can implement if you want after testing is over

Comment: So localstorage in the browser and device storage works the same way?

Id like to use the ionic native storage plugin though, but if I use this, the only way to test it would be in the device right? Or emulating it

Comment: The native storage plugin works the same way just accessing methods are different.. And yes using native plugin needs emulating or running the app in real device and there is a way you can use native plugin inside browser check this blog  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser.html